# 'str' does not support the buffer interface?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, cmd

I'm going through a basic socket tutorial (http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/) and I've run into an odd error that when sending data to the host I get the error

```
sock.sendall(message) 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

So the tutorial is kind of outdated with the newer version of python and maybe I'm using outdated code but I was hoping someone could take a look and find out why I'm having this problem. My thoughts are that maybe the HTTP command is wrong? But I've done some research and that seems to be correct. Thanks for your help!

```
import socket
import sys


#error handling
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as e:
    print ("Failed to create socket." + str(e[1]) + " . Error   message : " + e[1])
print ("Socket Created")


host = 'www.google.com' 
port = 80
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print ("Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting")
    sys.exit()
print ("IP address of " + host + " is " + remote_ip)

#connect to remote 
sock.connect((remote_ip, port))
print ("Socket Connected to " + host + "on ip " + remote_ip)

#send some data to client
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
try:
    #set the whole string
    sock.sendall(message) #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING
except socket.error:
    #send Failed
    print ("send failed")
    sys.exit()
print ("message sent successfully ")
```

Comment: That tutorial is outdated and for Python 2.

Comment: Yup totally works with the fixes. Thanks!